# How to create a cocoa pod locally and share it via email

Tags: xcode, frameworks, cocoapods, ios8

I have two frameworks that I have created and want to share it via cocoapods without putting them on github/git. If i provide the pod to a developer they shall be able to pull in the frameworks from it.

Is it possible to locally create that cocoapod and share it via email ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory you could do this by giving them the `foo.podspec` file you created along with your `foo.framework.` I personally think this would be a pain so I would instead recommend that you either use some sort of version control with a private repo ([CocoaPods supports more than just git](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#source)). Also, as you can see from that link, you can distribute your library as just a `zip` or `tar.gz` that you can host somewhere.

Overall you should aim for only having to share the `podspec` file instead of that and your code. You can also create [private specs repositories](http://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html) so you don't have to publicize your code but only have to share the directory of specs.